# NSStream Released while reading in, "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, nsstream

I have a view controller that is an NSStreamDelegate, I have a problem when the view is popped from the navigation controller while something is being streamed I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error. I have tried closing the stream, but it doesn't seem to stop it if there is a stream in progress. What is the proper way to handle this, can you delay the view from popping if something is being streamed?

```
#import "CameraViewer.h"

@implementation CameraViewer
@synthesize camService;
@synthesize currentDownload;

 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil theService:(NSNetService *)cameraService {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
        [self setCamService:cameraService];
    }
    return self;
}



// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self downloadAgain];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"view is going away");
    NSInputStream *istream;
    [camService getInputStream:&istream outputStream:nil];
    [istream close];
    NSLog(@"view is gone");
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}


- (void)downloadAgain{
        NSInputStream *istream;
        [camService getInputStream:&istream outputStream:nil];
        [istream retain];
        [istream setDelegate:self];
        [istream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [istream open];
}

#pragma mark NSStream delegate method

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)event {
        switch(event) {
            case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
                NSLog(@"Reading Stream");
                if (![self currentDownload]) {
                    [self setCurrentDownload:[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:409600]];
                }
                uint8_t readBuffer[4096];
                int amountRead = 0;
                NSInputStream * is = (NSInputStream *)aStream;
                amountRead = [is read:readBuffer maxLength:4096];
                [[self currentDownload] appendBytes:readBuffer length:amountRead];
                //NSLog(@"case 1");
                break;
            case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
                [(NSInputStream *)aStream close];
                UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[self currentDownload]];
                [self setCurrentDownload:nil];
                if(newImage != nil){
                    [imageView setImage:newImage];
                }
                [newImage release];
                [self performSelector:@selector(downloadAgain) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
}

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [[self camService] release];
    [[self currentDownload] release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you call `scheduleInRunLoop`. In that case, when you don't need the stream, you should also call

```
[istream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] 
                   forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

after you've closed the stream.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is whatever instance of the CameraViewer class (which is set to be the delegate) is being deallocated (causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the run loop) because you didn't retain it.

The solution is to either call retain on the CameraViewer class at instantiation, like so:

```
CameraViewer *cameraViewer = [[CameraViewer alloc] init];
[cameraViewer retain];
```